# MYSQL Select statements using distinct and count

Tags: mysql

Hello I am a beginner at mysql. I have a table like this

```
|Item no.|Location|
-------------------
|192     |Japan   |
|882     |Korea   |
|982     |China   |
|111     |China   |
|02      |Japan   |
|03      |Korea   |
|04      |Japan   |
```

I want the resulting table to be like this

```
|Location|NumberofItems|
------------------------
|Japan   |      3      |
|Korea   |      2      |
|China   |      2      |
```

My code doesn't seem to work. Here is my code:

```
SELECT distinct Location, count(*) as NumberofItems FROM Products inner join Products on Price = Price
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group by a specific column you get only the distinct values from that column. Then you can use aggregate functions like `count` on each group

```
SELECT Location, count(*) as NumberofItems 
FROM Products
GROUP BY Location
```

Answer (score 0):

You need GROUP BY command.

```
SELECT distinct location,count(*) as NumberofItems FROM products GROUP BY location;
```